# Why are questions allowed to have two similar tags?

Tags: support, tags

Why are questions allowed to have two similar tags?

For example, the following question has two tags assigned, [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) and [.net3.5](/questions/tagged/.net3.5).

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3726446/revisions, revision 5 or earlier.

Comment: *one* out of the four required tags suffices here...

Comment: Because they aren't the same tag

Comment: I like it, if I hit edit to correct spelling and see @Peter Mortensen in the *Rev* title. Nothing left to do. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contrary to the answers posted so far tagging with both tags is correct.

- The `.net3.5` tag is needed to indicate that either the question is about a specific feature of the version 3.5 of the .NET framework or to indicate that the user is using that specific version, and thus solutions that are not compatible with it are unacceptable.
- The `.net` tag is also needed for several reasons:

  - The answers qualify for the `.net` badge which indicates a knowledge about the entire .NET framework, including the specific 3.5 version
  - Many people favorite the main tag but not the version specific tag.
  - Similarly, many people ignore the main tag but not the specific tag.
  - Someone searching for a similar problem is very likely to search for `[.net] text` instead of `[.net3.5] text`.

Comment: Actually, the [.net] badge only indicates knowledge of the questions tagged [.net], not necessarily the framework as a whole. It's quite simple to master the "parent" tag while *only* staying within a specific domain (i.e. get said badge for only answering .NET 3.5 questions), due to the question volume.

Answer (score 0):

The `.net` tag is for questions generally concerning the .NET Framework, independent of the version, while the `.net3.5` tag should indicate a question is specific to that version. In this case I guess the OP wasn't certain whether his question applies to all versions or not, someone knowing should adequately retag.

Comment: having both tags make sence, as a lot of people that know about .net3.5 only look at quesions on the .net tag.

Comment: @Ian: In that case you should post this as answer here

Answer (score -1):

Well the tags aren't the same are they.  The `.net` refers to the .NET Framework as a whole.  The `.net3.5` refers specifically to version 3.5 of the Framework.

It should probably be retagged to just `.net3.5`

Comment: No, it shouldn't, because nobody subscribes to the `[.net3.5]` tag, whereas a whole bucketload of people look at `[.net]` questions.  Questions allow 5 tags for a reason; you're *supposed* to add both specific and general tags.  So, +1 for the first paragraph, -1 for the second.